# generate standardized beta coefficients from an adjusted GLM in R

Tags: r, glm

I run a simple univariate logistic regression where Group is a string ("patients", "controls") and is a factor and x is a numeric with the following line:
glmmodel <- glm(Group ~ x = mod, family = binomial, data = df)

looking at model output, I can see coefficients adjusted *but what I want are the standardized beta coefficients*

I have used lm.beta(glmmodel), which results in the following error: Error in x * w : non-numeric argument to binary operator. even when i dummy code group (0's and 1's) i still get the same error.

I have also used beta(glmmodel), which results in the following error: Error in beta(glmmodel) : argument "b" is missing, with no default

Edit: I tried using lm.beta(glmmodel) from the quantpsych package and received the following error:

Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct. Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.

Comment: Try library(QuantPsyc);
lm.beta(glmmodel )

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and got the following error:

Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
  Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.